# Problems compiling program with extern variable

Tags: c, storage-class-specifier

Inside main() function when I create a separate block (new pair of curly braces) like this one-:

```
int main(void){

    int x = 10;
    {
        extern int y;
        printf("\tNo. is %d\n", y);
        int y = 20;
    }
}
```

When I compile this code I come across an error :

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:12:9: error: declaration of ‘y’ with no linkage follows extern declaration
 int y = 20;
test.c:9:16: note: previous declaration of ‘y’ was here
 extern int y;
```

**But**

If the definitaion for int y is placed at end of the main function the code compiles and run perfectly okay.

What could be reason behind this error? According to my book if a variable is declared as extern then we can use it before defining it and the compiler will search in the whole file for definition of the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C distinguishes variables in file scope (= outside any function) and variables in a local scope.

The `y`-variable that you declare with `extern` and use in the `printf` refers to a variable in file scope. That variable is only declared and must be "defined" elsewhere. That is storage must be allocated for it.

If you you have the second declaration of `y` inside any of the `{}` this is a local variable that is different from the file scope variable. If it is outside, it is a declaration of a file scope variable and a "tentative definition" of that file scope variable. So in this later case you have a declaration that is visible where the variable is used, and somewhere else a definition such that storage is provided, and everything works fine.

Comment: Are you saying that extern variables can only be linked with file scope variables(global) and they won't be linked with any local variables?

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a variable with identical name twice in a block with same block scope.

Comment: And extern int and int are treated as different declarations but variable name is same (i.e y) so it won't compile?

Comment: Yes. It would not compile.

Answer (score 0):

yes there is problem there when you used extern there. that means this int y is defined globally in the same file or different file. but without defining y (globally) you are printing that extern value that's why its error for linker